# check room availability with date range

Tags: mysql, subquery

Hello i have 2 tables rooms and bookings but my table sturcture little bit different,
in bookings table there are roomid,date,status for example:

```
101,2012-12-10,0
101,2012-12-11,0
101,2012-12-12,1
101,2012-12-13,0
102,2012-12-10,0
102,2012-12-11,0
102,2012-12-12,0
```

and i would like to find available rooms between 2012-12-10 and 2012-12-13
according this request only room 102 should be return.

i've tried

```
SELECT id 
FROM status 
WHERE status='0' 
  AND date between '2012-12-10' AND '2012-12-13' 
GROUP BY id
```

it doesn't work because even find only one available row it returns true for 101

so 101 is available for 2012-12-11 then showing like available but not okay for our data range.

Comment: Is your datatype for the date column DateTime?

Comment: do you want to use between, or is it better to use >= and < ? if you also have a row `102,2012-12-13,1` does that mean that the room is not available in the interval? i think it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will select all rooms that have no row with `status=1` in the interval you select. Notice that I am not using `between`: if `status=1` on 13th of December, the room is still available in the interval, that's why I'm using `>= and <`:

```
SELECT roomid
FROM status
WHERE `date` >= '2012-12-10'
      AND `date` < '2012-12-13'
GROUP BY roomid
HAVING sum(status.status=1)=0
```

If there could also be some missing days in your table, and if that means that the room is not booked but also not available, you could also use this query:

```
SELECT roomid
FROM status
WHERE `date` >= '2012-12-10'
      AND `date` < '2012-12-13'
      AND status=0
GROUP BY roomid
HAVING count(*)=DATEDIFF('2012-12-13', '2012-12-10')
```

that checks that the number of days in the interval is equal to the number of rows with status=0.

Comment: i've edited this query like this but it doesn't work, where is wrong? SELECT ed.* FROM emlaklar ed INNER JOIN
((SELECT emlak_id FROM fiyatlar WHERE `tarih` between '2012-12-10' AND '2012-12-18' GROUP BY emlak_id HAVING sum(durum=1)=0) AS f ON ed.id = f.emlak_id)

Comment: @user1919682 i think you don't need the double `((`, you need just one and you can remove the closing `)` at the end

Comment: it works right now really interesting :) thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

If the date has a time associated with it you need to do something like this:

```
SELECT id 
FROM status 
WHERE status='0' 
  AND date between '2012-12-10 00:00:00' AND '2012-12-13 23:59:59' 
GROUP BY id
```

You can also use Date(date) instead of including times, but this might be less efficient.

Comment: i've tried but same because if you check the bookings table query can find available one free date like 2012-12-11, this date is available but 2012-12-12 is not. Results show like available but not allowed date range

Comment: Depending on what dates you want to be inclusive you just have to change the times/dates.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the following:

```
SELECT roomid 
FROM status s1
WHERE status='0' 
  AND date between '2012-12-10' AND '2012-12-13' 
  and not exists (select roomid
                  from status  s2
                  where status='1' 
                    AND date between '2012-12-10' AND '2012-12-13'
                    and s1.roomid = s2.roomid)
GROUP BY roomid
```

See [SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58797/6)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT rd.* 
FROM room_details rd 
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT roomid FROM bookings 
            WHERE roomid NOT IN (SELECT roomid FROM bookings 
                                WHERE STATUS =0 AND DATE BETWEEN '2012-12-10' AND '2012-12-13')
                ) AS a ON rd.roomid = a.roomid
```

Comment: yes this is worked, how can i join this query with room_details table?

Comment: Use output of this query as table and join this table with room details as select * from roomdetails rd inner join (above query) as a on rd.roomid =a.id

Comment: could you share full query please i couldn't understand exactly?

Answer (score 0):

The SQL BETWEEN condition will return the records where expression is within the range of value1 and value2 (inclusive). So row `101,2012-12-10,0` should be returned for above mentioned query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT roomid
FROM status
WHERE 'date_from' <= "2012-12-10"  AND 'date_to' > "2012-12-10" AND 'status'= 0;
```